# IOS Subscription currency formatter for vietnam Dong?

Tags: ios, subscription

I am using subscription for my app and displaying the currency for relevant country itunes Id

The price is displaying as "₫55,000"  but in app store for other apps the price is displaying as "55,000₫"

Please suggest which one is correct and is i need to display my price as "55,000₫"  what would i need to change in code level

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter1 setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter1 setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
[formatter1 setLocale:productInfo.priceLocale];
NSString *formattedPrice1 = [formatter1 stringFromNumber:productInfo.price];
NSLog(@"formattedPrice1 -- %@",formattedPrice1);
```

Comment: 1. No need to set the formatter behavior. 2. Why are you using Scientific style instead of Currency style?

Comment: by mistaken i pasted code wrongly below what the right code that i am using
    [formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setLocale:productInfo.priceLocale];
    NSString *formattedPrice = [formatter stringFromNumber:productInfo.price];

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. [Edit] your question with the correct code and details.